# Remove tcp entry from netstat -a

Tags: tcp, ping, netstat

I have a rather strange issue and no matter what I do or search, I cannot rectify it and have now decided to seek help here initially.

I have a cluster of servers, about 10 clustered together.

A few weeks ago, one of the servers stopped communicating with the master server. Upon investigation, I found that the slave server could no longer ping the master but the master was still able to ping and communicate with the slave but they were no longer clustered.

I figured it was a firewall issue somewhere on the master and searched for the possible rule causing this. Eventually, I totally flushed the rules and re-wrote them again but even after the flush, the slave could still not ping the master and had 100% packet loss.

Upon further investigation, a weird entry was found on the MASTER in netstat -a showing the slave listening locally even though the entry should not be there.

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4084            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 xxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.xx:5941 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 dex.xxxxxxx.co.u:domain 0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

The third entry is the slave and it is a remote server so should not be under Local Address if I am not mistaken.
This seems to be the cause of the lock out as far as I can see.
Here it is again.

```
]# netstat -ntlp | grep 9954
tcp        0      0 xx.99.1x7.x:53          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
9954/dnsmasq

~]# netstat -ntlp | grep 53
tcp        0      0 xx.99.1x7.x:53          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

I need assistance in removing this entry so the slave may be able to ping the master again. I have tried

```
tcpkill host xxx.xxxxxxxx.com
tcpkill host xx.99.1x7.x
```

but neither of these were able to remove the entry or allow ping.

Is there something I have missed? The master has not been rebooted as it is a production server.
Any suggestions woud be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that the address of your slave is configured as a local address in your master. The master doesn't ping the slave, it pings itself on the local address of the slave. The slave can't ping the master because the master assumes the return address is local and doesn't send the answer back to the slave.

Use `ip addr` to see the local addresses. You can remove the address with `ip addr del slave-ip dev device`, but you must find out where the address got set so that you can prevent that from happening again.

Comment: Thank you.
I found the entry to the IP


   `86: natbr45: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc             noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
        link/ether 11:11:00:2c:ce:ad brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet xx.99.1x7.x/24 brd xx.99.1x7.255 scope global natbr45
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever`


Trying to remove it is proving a problem


   ` ip addr del xx.99.1x7.x/24 dev natbr45
    RTNETLINK answers: Cannot assign requested address`